# Create EventMessage in Exchange Office 365

Tags: exchangewebservices, office365-restapi

Have been getting trouble with one issue which I guess someone can help me out. So we are pragmatically migrating emails from Office 365 to Office 365 and one scenario is in inbox we have got EventMessage type items. Here is a scenario;

Migration Happening from User A to User B

User A got an event invitation from other account (Lets say User C). So as part of migration we have to migrate the invitation which was received by User A from User C.

Using EWS when we try to read inbox this item is being read as MailMessage and it gets migrated however it becomes NORMAL Email instead of Event Invite. And we do not see any way to create an item in inbox with EventMessage type. Does anyone has any solution? We are happy to use REST API if that is possible,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this scenario isn't covered today by Outlook REST APIs that you are using.  EventMessage can only be generated by the service, as part of workflows that are kicked off when a new meeting is created on a calendar and when someone responds to the invite.  This is by design, because there business logic in these workflows dealing with delegates, and making sure the right actions happen when a meeting is updated or cancelled.  So, there is no way for you to create this event message by doing a POST on a message collection.

For your migration scenario, your best bet may be to use our older EWS SOAP APIs - [ExportItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff709523(v=exchg.150).aspx) and [UploadItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff709490(v=exchg.150).aspx) and see if that meets your needs.